# Design pattern for asynchronous calls in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, domain-driven-design, mvp

I'm designing a desktop application with multiple layers: the GUI layer (WinForms MVP) holds references to interfaces of adapter classes, and these adapters call BL classes that do the actual work.

Apart from executing requests from the GUI, the BL also fires some events that the GUI can subscribe to through the interfaces. For example, there's a `CurrentTime` object in the BL that changes periodically and the GUI should reflect the changes.

There are two issues that involve multithreading:

1. I need to make some of the logic
   calls asynchronous so that they don't block the GUI.
2. Some of the events the GUI recevies are fired from non-GUI threads.

At what level is it best to handle the multithreading? My intuition says that the Presenter is the most suitable for that, am I right? Can you give me some example application that does what I need? And does it make sense for the presenter to hold a reference to the form so it can invoke delegates on it?

**EDIT:** The bounty will probably go to Henrik, unless someone gives an even better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at using a `Task`-based BLL for those parts that can be described as "background operations" (that is, they're started by the UI and have a definite completion point). The [Visual Studio Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=18712f38-fcd2-4e9f-9028-8373dc5732b2) includes a document describing the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP); I recommend designing your BLL API in this way (even though the `async`/`await` language extensions haven't been released yet).

For parts of your BLL that are "subscriptions" (that is, they're started by the UI and continue indefinitely), there are a few options (in order of my personal preference):

1. Use a `Task`-based API but with a `TaskCompletionSource` that never completes (or only completes by being cancelled as part of application shutdown). In this case, I recommend writing your own `IProgress<T>` and `EventProgress<T>` (in the Async CTP): the `IProgress<T>` gives your BLL an interface for reporting progress (replacing progress events) and `EventProgress<T>` handles capturing the `SynchronizationContext` for marshalling the "report progress" delegate to the UI thread.
2. Use Rx's `IObservable` framework; this is a good match design-wise but has a fairly steep learning curve and is less stable than I personally like (it's a pre-release library).
3. Use the old-fashioned Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP), where you capture the `SynchronizationContext` in your BLL and raise events by queuing them to that context.

**EDIT 2011-05-17:** Since writing the above, the Async CTP team has stated that approach (1) is not recommended (since it somewhat abuses the "progress reporting" system), and the Rx team has released documentation that clarifies their semantics. I now recommend Rx for subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what type of application you are writing - for example - do you accept bugs? What are your data requirements - soft realtime? acid? eventually consistent and/or partially connected/sometimes disconnected clients?

Beware that there's a distinction between concurrency and asynchronocity. You can have asynchronocity and hence call method call interleaving without actually having a concurrently executing program.

One idea could be to have a read and write side of your application, where the write-side publishes events when it's been changed. This could lead to an event driven system -- the read side would be built from the published events, and could be rebuilt. The UI could be task-driven - in that a task to perform would produce a command that your BL would take (or domain layer if you so wish).

A logical next step, if you have the above, is to also go event-sourced. Then you would recreate internal state of the write-model through what has been previously committed. There's a google group about CQRS/DDD that could help you with this.

With regards to updating the UI, I've found that the IObservable interfaces in System.Reactive, System.Interactive, System.CoreEx are well suited. It allows you to skip around different concurrent invocation contexts - dispatcher - thread pool, etc, and it interops well with the Task Parallel Library.

You'd also have to consider where you put your business logic -- if you go domain driven I'd say you could put it in your application as you'd have an updating procedure in place for the binaries you distribute anyway, when time comes to upgrade, but there's also the choice of putting it on the server. Commands could be a nice way to perform the updates to the write-side and a convenient unit of work when connection-oriented code fails (they are small and serializable and the UI can be designed around them).

To give you an example, have a look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/5eea6700-1c79-4da6-9b68-efa480ed3a36), with this code, that adds a priority to the IObservable.ObserveOnDispatcher(...)-call:

```
    public static IObservable<T> ObserveOnDispatcher<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, DispatcherPriority priority)
    {
        if (observable == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        return observable.ObserveOn(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, priority);
    }

    public static IObservable<T> ObserveOn<T>(this IObservable<T> observable, Dispatcher dispatcher, DispatcherPriority priority)
    {
        if (observable == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();

        if (dispatcher == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dispatcher");

        return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<T>(o =>
        {
            return observable.Subscribe(
                obj => dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => o.OnNext(obj)), priority),
                ex => dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => o.OnError(ex)), priority),
                () => dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => o.OnCompleted()), priority));
        });
    }
```

The example above could be used like this [blog entry](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2010/06/rx-part-6-scheduling-and-threading.html) discusses

```
public void LoadCustomers()
{
    _customerService.GetCustomers()
        .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.NewThread)
        .ObserveOn(Scheduler.Dispatcher, DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle)
        .Subscribe(Customers.Add);
}
```

... So for example with a virtual starbucks shop, you'd have a domain entity that has something like a 'Barista' class, which produces events 'CustomerBoughtCappuccino' : { cost : '$3', timestamp : '2011-01-03 12:00:03.334556 GMT+0100', ... etc }. Your read-side would subscribe to these events. The read side could be some data model -- for each of your screens that present data -- the view would have a unique ViewModel-class -- which would be synchronized with the view in an observable dictionary [like this](http://www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx). The repository would be (:IObservable), and your presenters would subscribe to all of that, or just a part of it. That way your GUI could be:

1. Task driven -> command driven BL, with focus on user operations
2. Async
3. Read-write-segregated

Given that your BL only takes commands and doesn't on top of that display a 'good enough for all pages'-type of read-model, you can make most things in it internal, internal protected and private, meaning you can use System.Contracts to prove that you don't have any bugs in it (!). It would produce events that your read-model would read. You could take the main principles from [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) about the orchestration of workflows of yielded asynchronous tasks (IAsyncResults).

There are some [Rx design guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2010/10/28/rx-design-guidelines.aspx) you could read. And [cqrsinfo.com](http://cqrsinfo.com) about event sourcing and cqrs. If you are indeed interested in going beyond the async programming sphere into the concurrent programming sphere, Microsoft has released a well [written book](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee) for free, on how to program such code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. You have given me enough pointers to spend a month just reading about all of this :)

Comment: I'm glad ;). Send me a PM if you need a personal tutor. I do consulting.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the "Thread Proxy Mediator Pattern". Example here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/mediator_pattern.aspx)

Basically all method calls on your Adaptors run on a worker thread and all results are returned on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is using threads on the GUI, and then update your controls with [`Control.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx).

If you don't want to use threads in your GUI application, you can use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

The best practice is having some logic in your Forms to update your controls from outside, normally a public method. When this call is made from a thread that is not the MainThread, you must protect illegal thread accesses using `control.InvokeRequired/control.Invoke()` (where control is the target control to update).

Take a look to this [AsynCalculatePi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx) example, maybe it's a good starting point.

Comment: I know how Control.Invoke() behaves, but the question is about the design pattern and about best practices. Which control do I use for the Control.Invoke() - is it best practice to use the form? Does it mean that I need a reference to the form in my presenter, or do I call Invoke() from the form's code-behind?

Comment: @IIya: Ok, I uderstand. It depends on the circumstances, but normally you will write a logic to update a control, and you will use the target control to check InvokeRequired and then control.Invoke(). See my edits.